# Are combinatory logic terms always larger?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, combinatory-logic

So there [is an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) to convert lambda calculus terms to combinatory logic using SK combinators. It produces things that *explode* in size. I would like to know more about this explosion in size. I can't seem to think of a better algorithm however. I have heard of functional languages being practically compiled to combinators so it seems that a better algorithm must exist. I looked up [David Turner's paper](http://cs.anu.edu.au/courses/COMP3610/assignments/Asst1/Turner-Combinators.pdf) on the topic and he basically just says to apply a few optimizations and that they cause a "considerable improvement".

Does "considerable improvement" mean that the size drops to only a polynomial increase? Is there a known way to convert lambda terms to combinatory logic with only a polynomial (or less?) increase in size? If such an algorithm exists is it practical?

Comment: the paper is from 1979. there is much more modern/ recent thinking/ technology on how to translate code into logic eg with FPGAs & GPUs & generally wouldnt be based on functional languages....

Comment: Can you point me to them?

Comment: the research you cite is more theoretical "proof of principle"... it would be better if you cite the concept/ section about "polynomial increase in size" which seems to be the focus of your question... are you interested in the general theory of converting code into logic/ circuits, on the theoretical or applied side, or the theory of doing it efficiently, or both? the question is very crosscutting in its different aspects... maybe can figure out more in [chat]

Comment: 1) is there a way to import this to a chat? I can't seem to figure that out. 2) There is no section about polynomial increase in size and that is my problem. It doesn't actually say anything substantial (nor can I find any such references) about how much the increase in size is.

Comment: the comments can be imported to chat after a threshhold of separate posted comments. that is not necessary to start a chat. re polynomial increase it could be a "rumor" or "folklore" concept about this line of research, not sure. but where did you hear stuff like "it produces things that _explode_ in size"; it would be helpful to be more specific etc...

Comment: I have never heard anything about a polynomial increase in size; that is my own hope and not in anyway founded in anything anyone has said. I'm not even really fixated on it being polynomial, that was just an example of what an algorithm might turn out to give. In the paper it doesn't say "explode" but it does say that the increase is impractical. If you run some examples yourself you will see it "explode" as I have said. Additionally the wikipedia article says it grows as $\Theta(3^n)$. If that doesn't mean "explode" to you I don't know what does.

Comment: sorry now realize the ref to "combinatory logic" in the question has nothing directly to do with circuits & that was my misconception. further looking into this/ analysis, it may be active area of research & therefore maybe this question would fit better on [cstheory.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not an expert on this but here are two historical papers that seem to be closely relevant to the question and it is possibly a semi active area of research. Turner proposed a set of combinators that can be reduced to SK combinators. this next paper argues that Turner combinators even not reduced to SK combinators leads to exponential blowup (and that presumably the reduction would to SK terms be even larger). but then the 2nd paper says there is an efficient O(n log n) space algorithm based on Turner combinators. (it appears maybe that claims have been made about polynomial efficiency that are regarded as not fully demonstrated/ unproved & are therefore regarded as conjectures...?) anyway apparently real functional evaluation in applied languages typically does not use combinator method so implementors are not too concerned with issues of theoretical efficiency of evaluation of functional expressions by combinator translation.

- [What is an Efficient Implementation of the λ-calculus?](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/daimipb/article/viewFile/6574/5697) / Frandsen, Sturtivant (1991) (see p.18)

  > Furthermore, we show that implementations based upon Turner Combinators or Hughes Super-combinators have complexities $2^{Ω(ν)}$, i.e. an exponential lower bound.
  > It is open whether any implementation of polynomial complexity, $ν^{O(1)}$, exists, although some implementations have been implicitly claimed to have this complexity.
- [Translation of Turner Combinators in O(n log n) space](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019085900663) / Noshita (1985)

  > A practical method for representing Turner Combinators is presented, which needs only O(n log n) space in the worst case for translating lambda expressions of length n.

Comment: perfect! I found this paper also after searching for those two papers. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001908790161X
Thanks!